# Load balancing not working OSB

Tags: oracle11g, soa, servicebus, osb, bus

I am trying to understand the Oracle Service Bus Load Balancing.  I have:

- One weblogic server 10.3.6.0, with
- 3 Managed servers (`lb`,`osb1`,`osb2`):

  - 2 Managed servers are in cluster configuration:

    - `osb1` - with port 7101 and
    - `osb2` - with port 7202
  - The manager Server called `lb` was configured as proxy server with port 7301.

Using Eclipse, I have done a "Hello World" application ( I used a proxy service and wsdl). But when I go to browser with http://localhost:7301/osb-101-helloworld/HelloWorld the application is not working,
    If I go to `http://localhost:7001/osb-101-helloworld/HelloWorld` the application works and I can see the code using `?wsdl` instruction at the end of the URL. Code displays the following information:

```
 <WL5G3N0:service name="HelloWorld">
    <WL5G3N0:port binding="WL5G3N1:HelloWorldSOAP" name="HelloWorldSOAP">
    <WL5G3N2:address location="http://gaia:7001/osb-101-helloworld/HelloWorld"/>

**gaia is the server name.**
```

The 7001 port is used by AdminServer.

I am using this blog [Oracle Fusion Middleware - Oracle Service Bus & SOA Suite--Gang Of Two : OSB Clustering & Load Balancer](http://abhinavgupta3.blogspot.com/2012/02/osb-clustering-load-balancer.html) as a guide, but I don't know how to make the "hello world" application work using correct manager server (7301 - proxyserver).

Comment: I don't see how this is this is related to the Oracle database at all. Can you make it clearer?

Comment: It is related to Middleware and SOA section.

Comment: What happens when you hit 7101 or 7202? This will tell us if OSB is properly deployed on the managed servers.

Comment: Hi, 7101 or 7202 gives me 404 Not found, How can I verify OSB deployment on managed servers? Maybe that could be my error, but OSB  page (sbconsole) shows me all managed servers that I have...

Comment: That tells me that when you make a change in AdminServer, it's not publishing to your Managed Servers. - log into /console and check Deployments > ALSB * and make sure they all Target your Cluster and not AdminServer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/doc.1111/e15022/cluster.htm#OSBDG164 and Appendix B that is linked from it.  You need to use the WLST script or the Wizard to properly create the extended Managed Servers visible to SBConsole.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I solved the problem, I had to create a new weblogic domain using cluster configuration, that is because I was working with an extended weblogic with cluster configuration. Reading some Oracle Documents, using extended domain may affect some oracle bus deployments targets.